# Wave is being discontinued! Other good remote collaboration tools?

Tags: tools, productivity

The news just came across the Google blog that Wave is going to go away in the not too distant future. [Clicky for the story.](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/update-on-google-wave.html) This is a real shame for my team who has been making heavy use of Wave as a remote collaboration tool.  Looks like we need a new platform.  What tools does your remote team like to use to collaborate online?

Comment: Community wiki candidate?

Comment: -1 offtopic.  Probably a good question for the webapps stackexchange site: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/  Like maybe this question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3469/whats-the-best-app-for-collaboration-in-a-startup

Comment: I can see how this is tangential to game development but like Tetrad said, it should definitely be asked in the webapps stackexchange site. -1 :(

Answer (score 2):

PyCon had a lot of success using Etherpad. Even though the main hosted service has been taken down, you can either run it yourself or [use one of the many public sites](http://etherpad.org/etherpadsites.html). Chris Ball's [openetherpad](http://openetherpad.org) has worked well for me before.